# MYSQL GROUP BY 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 2 tables:

```
games
softwares
```

And I have the rows:

games:

```
id | ref_id | title
 1 |   20   |  nikita
 1 |   18   |  simba
```

softwares:

```
id | ref_id | title
 1 |   18   |  adware
 1 |   19   |  acdsee
```

Now I want to do a GROUP BY ref_id and get:

```
20
18
19
```

Comment: think what you really want is an UNION :) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html (with a group by ..)

Answer (score 2):

```
select ref_id from games
union 
select ref_id from softwares
```

this answer is according to your result needed and table structure you have mention.